# How can I bring the program behind the pop up window?

Tags: java

As you can see below in my code when clicks on the `helpsection` method a PDF file opens. I was wondering instead of the PDF being behind the program, how can I bring that window in front of the program? I tried using `Desktop.setVisible(true);` However, I had no luck I got the error messages.

[image]

[image]

**PROGRAM CODE**

```
import java.util.Scanner; //taking input from user
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.Desktop;

public static void helpsection() {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("CVliamdocherty.pdf"));
            Desktop.setVisible(true);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to go back into the program to select a course to find out your grade?");
        System.out.println("You can enter 'Yes' or 'No' only.");
        outcome2 = userinput.next();
        if (outcome2.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            step1();
        } else if (outcome2.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
            System.out.println((username)+" thanks for using Liam's UCAS grade calculator.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else { 
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid value.");
            System.out.println("The program now will re run, make sure to enter the correct value next time.");
            step1();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Assuming you are using Swing/AWT, you could simply call [`Window#toBack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toBack()).

Comment: Show the code for your frame/window

Comment: When you say “behind the program” I assume you mean behind the terminal where you’re running.  It’s unusual to mix terminal interaction with desktop actions.  If you want to control the behavior of windows, make your application a GUI and show your document in a dialog window you create, instead of using Desktop.open.

Answer (score -3):

Try this to open your pdf doucument using default pdf viewer

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(new File("CVliamdocherty.pdf"));
```

I haven't tried your code because I'm currently using Linux and it requires one to use xdg-open to open a document with default application. So just try and see if it works

Comment: You probably didn't notice, but this is exactly what the OP did. He is trying to display the PDF viewer in front of his GUI.

Comment: @Cardinal What I understood is the pdf file opens but you have to like switch to the pdf application to view the pdf document. What I just posted opens the pdf in default pdf viewer and switches focus to pdf viewer application

Comment: I don't see a difference between `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("CVliamdocherty.pdf"));` and `Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(new File("CVliamdocherty.pdf"));`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work? I thought it did before but it didn't.